how to add data labels in salesforce labs lightingWebchartJs
im using salesforce lwcc https://salesforcelabs.github.io/LightningWebChartJS/docs/api/chart.html
How to show value on each stack and cumulative value on top of the bar and also in legend each with stack value?
Currently how its displaying
enter image description here
`

                <template for:each={formattedData} for:item="item" for:index="index">
                    <c-data
                        key={item}
                        label={item.label}
                        detail={item.detail}
                        backgroundcolor={item.backgroundcolor}
                        stack=1>
                    </c-data>
                    </template>
</c-dataset> 
<c-title text="Sample Dashboard"></c-title>
<c-legend position="right"></c-legend>
 <c-cartesian-axis axis="x" stacked="true" ></c-cartesian-axis>
 <c-cartesian-axis axis="y" stacked="true"></c-cartesian-axis>

`
 myCustomTooltipFunction(tooltipItems){
        console.log('called',JSON.stringify(tooltipItems))
        console.log(tooltipItems.value+'k')
        return (tooltipItems.value+'k')
        
    }

